# Avoid Google Analytics to count unique goal URL twice

Tags: google-analytics

I have a Google Analytics goal (event) and it is set to fire when people reach a certain page with specific values/parameters included in the page URL. 
I have set it up in GTM.

You can see the tag on the left and the trigger on the right:

[image]

Now the results after a couple of days shows that some goals URL from the sales have been counted twice:

[image]

This could happen when somebody clicks on the link it has received by email a second time.

My question is: is there a way to avoid in Google Analytics (or GTM) for a specific URL to be recorded as a conversion twice (or more). 
Need only to be counted once.

For example, a specific goal URL could look like this:

```
/sp_ups01.php?item=1&cbreceipt=NSWHVARR&time=1557214622&cbpop=015B4567&cbaffi=xxxxx&cupsellreceipt=NSWHVARR&cname=Joe+Jonathan&cemail=xxxx@gmail.com&ccountry=FR&czip=74950&cbskin=18012&cbfid=30555&cbf=BJFBVASN4X
```

And I don't want GA to count it twice, never.

Comment: You have a lot of data in those URLs that is against GA's terms of service to record - I suggest reading https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6366371?hl=en As to your question, if a goal's conditions are met, and it has not been converted yet in that session, it will count as a conversion. You would have to prevent the goal's conditions from being met in order to prevent a conversion.